# psqlexception error de sintaxis cerca de "="

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

Estoy creando un metodo para obtener los records de **clients** que tienen un determinado **userid**, la tabla client contiene las columnas:**clientid,name,userid** igualmente la clase Client contiene los 3 parametros **clientid,name,userid**.

Pero la query que e creado para la obtención de dichos datos parece tener algún error y no se cual sea.

El metodo:

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    public Set getClientsByUserID(String userid) {
        Set clients = new HashSet();
        try {
            String queryString = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE=?";
            connection = getConnection();
            ptmt = connection.prepareStatement(queryString);
            ptmt.setString(1, userid);
            resultSet = ptmt.executeQuery();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                Client client = extractClientFromResultSet(resultSet);
                clients.add(client);
            }
            return clients;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (resultSet != null)
                    resultSet.close();
                if (ptmt != null)
                    ptmt.close();
                if (connection != null)
                    connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

El error que obtengo:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERRORE: errore di sintassi a o presso "="
  Posizione: 28
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2183)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:143)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:106)
    at db.dao.ClientDAO.getClientsByUserID(ClientDAO.java:48)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, el error fue mio, un simple descuido al escribir la query :

```
 String queryString = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE=?";
```

En la clausula **WHERE** falta el nombre de la columna osea **userid**, entonces cambiando:

```
String queryString = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE userid=?";
```

el problema es solucionado.